# how do I hide form.errors until its active

Tags: html, css, django

So on my login page, I see a red line(the border property of class field5 from CSS) appear above the input fields before actually putting in the credentials, I want it to disappear until a user actually hits an error. when someone hits an error it works fine, just that the red line is constant before an actual error. thnx for any help.

```
  <div class="field5">
    {{form.errors}}
  </div>

.field5 {
  border: 2px solid #d10a0a;
  font-family: Circular Std Book;
  background-color: #d10a0a;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: You may also want to look into [pseudo classes for form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation#Visual_styling_of_constraint_validation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a condition to check if the `form.errors` contains at least an error by checking the *truthiness*, so:

```
{% if form.errors %}
    <div class="field5">
        {{ form.errors }}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```